# Gradle sync failed: Cause: tried to access method. After updating gradle 2.3 to 4.0.1

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I just updated project gradle from 2.3 to 4.0.1. Android studio version 4.0.1 and 3.6.3

tried to access method org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultModuleVersionIdentifier.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V from class org.gradle.api.plugins.AndroidMavenPlugin$8

build.gradle

```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.50'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
        classpath "com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'

    }
     }

    allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/cometchat/CometChat'

        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

        maven { url "https://github.com/syrjs/maven/raw/master"}
        //  maven { url "https://github.com/paypal/paypalcheckout-android/raw/nativeSDK"}


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle app level

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dousic.music"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.0.8"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
        aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }
    }

    //Signing configurations for build variants "release"
//    signingConfigs {
//        release {
//            storeFile file("F:\\Samsung_jks\\galaxy_dousic.jks")
//            storePassword "cybernext123"
//            keyAlias "dousic"
//            keyPassword "cybernext123"
//        }
//    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            // signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "5120M"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })






    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1"
//    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
//    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'



    //implementation "com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.8"
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.3'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    implementation 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.5'
    implementation 'com.splitwise:tokenautocomplete:1.3.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    //  implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'
    //implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    /* implementation 'com.inscripts:CometChat:7.9.1'
        implementation 'com.inscripts:CometChatUI:7.9.1'*/
    implementation 'com.inscripts:CometChat:7.33.0'
    implementation 'com.inscripts:CometChatUI:7.33.0'

    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.4'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.3'
    implementation project(path: ':library')
    implementation project(path: ':videocompressor')
    //facebook
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    //Google login
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    //Twiiter
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1'
    // (Optional) Monetize using mopub
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-mopub:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3'
    implementation 'com.github.pedroSG94:AutoPermissions:1.0.3'
    //Showcase lib
    implementation 'com.github.mreram:ShowCaseView:1.0.5'
    // full exoplayer library
    // implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.2'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    //Audio player design
    implementation 'net.the4thdimension:audio-wife:1.0.3'
    //Comment loading libery
    implementation 'com.ethanhua:skeleton:1.1.1'
    implementation 'io.supercharge:shimmerlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.7.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

    //Strip
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:9.0.0'
    implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.14.2'

    //Exo player
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.2.0'





    // implementation 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android-assembly:3.6.1'
    // implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.22.0'
    /*  implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }*/
    // implementation 'com.applozic.communication.uiwidget:mobicomkitui:5.8.4'
    //  implementation 'com.github.takusemba:spotlight:1.6.0'
    // implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation project(':library')
    implementation project(':IAP5Helper')
    // implementation 'com.paypal.pyplcheckout:nativexo:3.4.5'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```